# I want to take some infromation from website with jsoup into android

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I want to add some information from this website "http://diyanet.gov.tr/tr/namazvakitleri". In this website there is a select-option menu and the data is related with more select-option menu.

I mean if somebody choose select menu `id=State` and than choose select menu `id=City` the information is shown. The sample Html code is below. when state and city are choose the last information is appeared. I want to select `selected option value of state` than `selected option value of city` after that I use the data of div `class=vakitler` in my app. However I cannot take these data from this website properly. can anybody help me pls.

```
<DIV id="stateHtml">
<SELECT name="State" id="State" style="width: 113px;"><OPTION value="">Seciniz</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="500">ADANA</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="501">ADIYAMAN</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="502">AFYON</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="503">AĞRI</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="504">AKSARAY</OPTION>
<OPTION value="505">AMASYA</OPTION> 
<OPTION selected="selected" value="506">ANKARA</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="507">ANTALYA</OPTION>

<SELECT name="City" id="City" style="width: 113px;">
<OPTION value="">Seciniz</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="9205">AKYURT</OPTION> 
<OPTION selected="selected" value="9206">ANKARA</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="9207">AYAŞ</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="9208">BALA</OPTION> 
<OPTION value="9209">BEYPAZARI</OPTION> 
</SELECT></DIV>

<DIV class="vakitler">
<DIV id="liImsak"><SPAN>İmsak</SPAN><SPAN id="spImsak">03:41</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV id="liGunes"><SPAN>Güneş</SPAN><SPAN id="spGunes">05:30</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV id="liOgle"><SPAN>Öğle</SPAN><SPAN id="spOgle">13:02</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV id="liIkindi"><SPAN>İkindi</SPAN><SPAN id="spIkindi">16:55</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV id="liAksam"><SPAN>Akşam</SPAN><SPAN id="spAksam">20:22</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV id="liYatsi"><SPAN>Yatsı</SPAN><SPAN id="spYatsi">22:02</SPAN></DIV>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this sample app:

```
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.jsoup.Connection;
    import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
    import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
    import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.HashMap;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        TextView dataView;
        Spinner countrySpinner, stateSpinner;
        HashMap<String, String> countryMap, stateMap;
        Button button;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country);
            stateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state);
            dataView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String countryName = countrySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String countryId = countryMap.get(countryName);
                    new StateSpinnerTask(countryId).execute();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });


            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (countrySpinner != null && countrySpinner.getSelectedItem() != null &&
                            stateSpinner.getSelectedItem() != null) {
                        String countryName = countrySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                        String stateName = stateSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        String countryId = countryMap.get(countryName);
                        String stateId = stateMap.get(stateName);

                        if (countryId != null && stateId != null)
                            new PrintDataTask(countryId, stateId).execute();

                    }


                }
            });

            new CountrySpinnerTask().execute();
        }

        private class StateSpinnerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {
            String countryId;

            public StateSpinnerTask(String countryId) {

                this.countryId = countryId;
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
                stateMap = new HashMap<>();
                ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();


                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect("http://diyanet.gov.tr/PrayerTime/" +
                            "FillMainPageState?countryCode="
                            + countryId).ignoreContentType(true).get();

                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(doc.body().text().toString());
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);

                        stateMap.put(jsonObject.get("Text").toString(),
                                jsonObject.get("Value").toString());

                        arrayList.add(jsonObject.get("Text").toString());

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return arrayList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                stateSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

        private class CountrySpinnerTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, ArrayList<String>> {

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... params) {
                countryMap = new HashMap<>();
                ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

                Document document = null;
                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect("http://diyanet.gov.tr/en/home").get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (document != null) {


                    Element countryElement = document.select("select[id=Country]").first();
                    Elements countryElements = countryElement.getElementsByTag("option");

                    for (Element element : countryElements) {

                        countryMap.put(element.text(), element.attr("value"));
                        arrayList.add(element.text());

                    }
                }

                return arrayList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> arrayList) {

                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayList);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            }
        }

        private class PrintDataTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
            String countryName, stateName;

            public PrintDataTask(String countryName, String stateName) {
                this.countryName = countryName;
                this.stateName = stateName;
            }

            @Override
            protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {

                    Connection.Response response = Jsoup
                            .connect("http://diyanet.gov.tr/PrayerTime/MainPrayerTimesSet")
                            .ignoreContentType(true)
                            .data("countryName", countryName)
                            .data("name", stateName)
                            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                            .execute();

                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.parse().body().text().toString());

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                return jsonObject;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                if (jsonObject != null)
                    try {
                        dataView.setText(jsonObject.get("Imsak")
                                + " " + jsonObject.get("Gunes")
                                + " " + jsonObject.get("Ogle")
                                + " " + jsonObject.get("Ikindi")
                                + " " + jsonObject.get("Aksam")
                                + " " + jsonObject.get("Yatsi"));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
        }


    }
```

Full source code you can download from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlhqd6yhxdp2xj9/sampleApp.zip?dl=0)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. nearly I study this issue about 3 weeks. thanks again. my best respects...

Comment: @MehmetGÜL If you've spent about 3 weeks, you can spend another second and mark matric's answer as "accepted".